# How to fs.writefile after ctx.body in Koa?

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa

I'd like to get the app response first, then the app writes file, What should I do in Koa?

Comment: What does your current code look like?

Comment: I think this might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26516082/running-code-after-the-response-has-been-sent-by-koa As far as I understand it you might "await/yield" the next middleware function which sends the response. After that function has returned you can write your file. I haven't tried it though.